# nginx, dns - domain.com resolves but subdomain.domain.com doesn't

Tags: nginx, subdomain, domain-name-system

I am going to pull my hair out!

I have a website domain.com with the following virtual host configuration **/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain**:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi-gen.conf;
        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localcerts/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localcerts/privateKey.key;

        server_name domain.com;
        root /var/www/wordpress;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi-gen.conf;
        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

it works great. Both domain.com and the redirection from www to non-www.
I also have this virtual host configuration **/etc/nginx/sites-available/owncloud** for my cloud.domain.com subdomain:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name cloud.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # enforce https
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localcerts/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localcerts/privateKey.key;
        server_name cloud.domain.com;

        root /var/www/owncloud;

        client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size

        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
        rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

        index index.php index.html;

        error_page 403 = /core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 = /core/templates/404.php;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }
        location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
                deny all;
        }
        location / {
                # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;
                rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                try_files $1 = 404;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                expires 30d;
                # Optional: Don't log access to assets
                access_log off;
        }
}
```

But cloud.domain.com doesn't work! I tried to ping it and it does not resolve to my ip.

Also the weird thing is that i have another vps with the exact configurations using a different domain, lets say domain2.com. In my other vps everything works fine. Both domain2.com and cloud.domain2.com resolve to my vps ip.

I also have identical directory structure.

- website : /var/www/wordpress
- owncloud : /var/www/owncloud

I am using the nameservers from my domain name provider (in both cases).

i have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a CNAME for cloud.domain.com that points at domain.com.  It should look something like this:

```
cloud.domain.com   300   IN   CNAME   domain.com
```

Alternately, you could do a wildcard domain entry:

```
*.domain.com   300   IN   CNAME   domain.com
```

Note that a wildcard will direct *any* requests that don't have explicit DNS entries.  So "anyrandombogusname.domain.com" would resolve to domain.com's IP address.

Comment: This worked for me. However I would like to point out that if you're running with a CDN like Cloudflare, you have to also put the CNAME entry at their DNS Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not list your DNS configuration, but `subdomain.domain.com` would require specific `CNAME` entries in the nameserver to function correctly.

Comment: But in my other domain's dns configuration i haven't made any CNAME entries for the cloud subdomain. So what should my CNAME entry be? cloud --> myip?

Comment: `bar.example.com.        CNAME  foo.example.com.` is a quick and dirty example of what a `CNAME` would look like. If your other configuration isn't requiring it, then I may be incorrect about you needing it but I would try it and see if once it propagates if that resolves the issue for you.

Comment: Because example.com (main domain) resolves to your nginx server directly.